# Why does this github workflow fail when trying to yarn install this dependency?

Tags: yarnpkg, github-actions

So I have a forked repo with a github workflow setup, which fails when trying to yarn install a dependency due to permission rights:

```
Run yarn install
yarn install v1.22.10
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error Command failed.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@github.com/boringcrypto/BoringSolidity.git
Directory: /home/runner/work/joe-core/joe-core
Output:
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.112.3' to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Error: Process completed with exit code 128.
```

It seems like the machine doesnt have permission to install this dependency. This is how the dependency is defined in the package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@boringcrypto/boring-solidity": "boringcrypto/BoringSolidity#e06e943",
}
```

This is the .yaml file defining the action:

```
#  workflow pipeline
name: sushiswap

on: ["push", "pull_request"]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        node: ["14.x", "12.x"]
        os: ["ubuntu-latest"]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
         ref: ${{github.event.pull_request.head.ref}}
         repository: ${{github.event.pull_request.head.repo.full_name}}

      - name: Nodejs  ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          check-latest: true

      - name: Install and Compile
        run: |
          yarn install
          yarn build
      - name: Test and Coverage
        run: |
          yarn test
  mythx:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      MYTHX_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.MYTHX }}

    steps:
      - name: Nodejs 14.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: "14.x"
          check-latest: true

      - name: Set up Python 3.8
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.8

      - name: Install MythX CLI
        run: python -m pip install mythx-cli
      - name: Print version info
        run: |
          python3 -V
          mythx version
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
         ref: ${{github.event.pull_request.head.ref}}
         repository: ${{github.event.pull_request.head.repo.full_name}}

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn install

      - name: Submit contracts
        run: mythx analyze
```

Comment: I am not sure, but how about `"@boringcrypto/boring-solidity": "https://github.com/boringcrypto/BoringSolidity#e06e943"`?

Comment: It's a public repo though. Shouldn't it be easily installed?

Comment: If HTTPS works and original SSH not, that might because SSH key is not setup correctly on runner machine.

Comment: Does this help? https://gist.github.com/taoyuan/bfa3ff87e4b5611b5cbe